# Ruby curb postfield.file fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, curl

So per the doc and other sources I try

> > Curl::PostField.file('fname', 'path-to-file)

Result : curl:err:invalidpostfielderror. Cannot convert non content field to string

What am I missing?!  File.exists(path-to-file is true

Comment: Can you please explain exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: Trying to send a file through a curb http post

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using curb to upload a large zip:

```
    c = Curl::Easy.new(url)
    c.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer #{token}"
    c.multipart_form_post = true
    c.on_failure { 
        # something
    }
    c.on_success { |data|       
        #something   
    }   
    c.http_post(Curl::PostField.content('id', my_id),
                Curl::PostField.file('zip', "path/to/my.zip"))
```